# Retrieving the passed ID

Tags: php

I wonder if you guys could help me. I have a table called modules and within it it has moduleID, moduleTitle, moduleCode etc.

A checkbox is populated next to each module that is displayed and the value of the checkbox is the moduleID. When a user checks the modules and click submit they get passed onto another page. On this other page I have managed to retrieve the moduleID's which have been checked but I am having trouble in turning these moduleID so that I can display the moduleTitle, moduleCode etc for the ones that have been checked on this new page.

I have used the following code but no luck  :confused:

```
  <?php

$cats_upload = "";
    foreach($_POST['module'] as $cats) // errors if no modules are selected
    {
      echo '<p>Module data moduleID: '.$cats.'</p>';

    }
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM modules WHERE moduleID ='".$cats."'");


$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //count the output amount

if($productCount > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  

    $moduleTitle = $row["moduleTitle"];


        $cats_upload .= "<tr><td>$moduleTitle</td></tr>"; 

    }
} else { 
    $cats_upload = "<tr><td>No modules have been selected</td></tr>";
}

?>
```

If anyone has any suggestions to what it might be, please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cats_upload = "";

if (!empty($_POST['module'])) {

    foreach ($_POST['module'] as $moduleID) {
      $modules[] = $moduleID;
    }

    $module_list = implode(',', $modules);

    $sql = "SELECT moduleTitle FROM modules WHERE moduleID IN (" . $module_list . ")";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in $sql: " . mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $cats_upload .= "<tr><td>" . $row['moduleTitle'] . "</td></tr>";
    }

} else {
    $cats_upload .= "<tr><td>No modules have been selected</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$cats = array();
foreach($_POST['module'] as $cat) // errors if no modules are selected
{
  echo '<p>Module data moduleID: '.$cat.'</p>';
  $cats[] = intval($cat); // Assumption: ids are numeric
}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM modules WHERE moduleID IN (".implode(',', $cats).")");
```

That should give you an SQL result with all matching modules.